# How to pass to a java function an array of records?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I need to pass from Delphi to a java function (made by me) an array of record :

```
TmyRec = record
  url: string;
  username: string;
  password: string;
end;
TMyRecs: Tarray<TmyRec>
```

How can I declare my java function to pass something like `TMyRecs` (or something similar the idea is to pass the information about `url,username,string` to java)?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking... Java does not have records.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I know I just want to find a way to pass a list of url,username,password to java (with or without record)

Comment: You need to define Java class that holds three strings and then pass collection (list) of such objects.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar what do you think is better, TJArrayList or TJCollection ?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I will use JList :) thanks :)

Comment: Collection is basic collection interface in Java - List interface extends Collection and ArrayList is one of the implementations of List interface. List is probably good choice as it is rather close to what you want from array functionality.